# Hover effect using Styled Components in in React don't work

Tags: reactjs, hover, styled-components

Don't know why hover effect code on button in StyledComponents is not working, in React app.
Can You please look at the code ? Thanks !

```
 export const StyledButton = styled.button`
  width: 12vh;
  background-color: ${colors.buttonColor};
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -4px rgba(237, 38, 38, 0.51);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -4px rgba(237, 38, 38, 0.51);
  height: 4vh;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  & :hover {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
`;

    <StyledButton>
          <Link to="/main" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <StyledParagraph>Go without</StyledParagraph>
          </Link>
        </StyledButton>
```

Comment: you have an extra space, it should be `&:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need correct selector.

In styled components, if you are styling the component itself, you don't need to write "&:hover", you can write ":hover" instead.

Both selectors are correct, use either one. If I apply styles to the styled component itself, I usually don't write the "&" sign.

Instead

```
  & :hover {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
```

Do you need write

```
  :hover {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
```

Below code with correct selector for hover.

```
export const StyledButton = styled.button`
  width: 12vh;
  background-color: ${colors.buttonColor};
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -4px rgba(237, 38, 38, 0.51);
  height: 4vh;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  :hover {
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
`;
```